# How to get the process id of a google chrome launched by Flutter WEb?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to get the process id of a google chrome launched by Flutter WEB ?

I have another script (NodeJs) launch Flutter Web . something like this:

```
const child = spawn("flutter run -d chrome --web-port=49430 main.dart")
```

My goal is to close the chrome browser opened by Flutter

I tried
`child.kill()` but this kills the dart process, not the web browser

I even tried to kill by port using  https://www.npmjs.com/package/fkill `fkill(":49430")`

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#subprocesspid), you can retrieve process ID of the spawn from the pid argument, such as:

```js
const grep = spawn('grep', ['ssh']);
console.log(`Spawned child pid: ${grep.pid}`);
```

In your example: `child.pid`